# Read/Write from RandomAccessFile in Java

Tags: java, file, random-access

I am trying my hands on using RandomAccessFile. What I'm doing is trying to store messages in the file and try to get all messages from one pointer to another

```
//file is the RandomAccessFile
//newLine is just new line
```

How I'm Storing:

```
//I want to store a message per line
public void store(long idx, String message){

   file.seek(idx);
   file.write(message);
   file.write(newLine)
}
```

This is how I fill the file:

```
void createDummy(String location) throws IOException {

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        long l = i;
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

            b.append((char)r.nextInt(26)+65);
        }

        String str = b.toString();
        store(l, str);
        System.out.println("Stored "+str);
    }

}
```

This was the output:

```
Stored BYOENDRWEBUVGIFR
Stored HNXRKZWPAZUYCUHN
Stored RPRRAXWRBFSRSHJD
Stored AGTJXZMCFXENBQOH
Stored QLWXLIBKRPELYHPR
Stored VBUOVQICIOOTOTYK
Stored HPDZRPUGIYAFBGJE
Stored ZGLAIXTBGVCLJAGC
Stored UZKUXCWGCIVJLMAF
Stored RIXZSEDXQPAVDWEK
```

Reading...how I'm reading:

```
//I want to retrieve all messages from "from" to "to"
```

public void retrieve(long from, long to){

```
 long start = from;
 file.seek(start);

 while(start < to){ 
    System.out.println(file.readLine());
    start++;
    file.seek(start);
  }
}
```

Calling  retrieve(3,9); gives the below output// Retrieve from 3 to 9;

```
Read NRPRAGTJQLWXLVBUOVQHPDZRPUZGLAIXTBUZKUXCWGCRIXZSEDXQPAVDWEKBT                    WNWFVVYDPEMCSFVQ                                RXCZSNOBEPPDKNBB                                            LCPFDVUXWETHVWJQ                                                        CPCCDTSOCLSEXIST                                                                    QZFCQWMQVEXTOGNG                                                                                SSKTXOYMOBETGVWN                                                                                            DWYIMILEXQMSNUBJ
Read RPRAGTJQLWXLVBUOVQHPDZRPUZGLAIXTBUZKUXCWGCRIXZSEDXQPAVDWEKBT                    WNWFVVYDPEMCSFVQ                                RXCZSNOBEPPDKNBB                                            LCPFDVUXWETHVWJQ                                                        CPCCDTSOCLSEXIST                                                                    QZFCQWMQVEXTOGNG                                                                                SSKTXOYMOBETGVWN                                                                                            DWYIMILEXQMSNUBJ
Read PRAGTJQLWXLVBUOVQHPDZRPUZGLAIXTBUZKUXCWGCRIXZSEDXQPAVDWEKBT                    WNWFVVYDPEMCSFVQ                                RXCZSNOBEPPDKNBB                                            LCPFDVUXWETHVWJQ                                                        CPCCDTSOCLSEXIST                                                                    QZFCQWMQVEXTOGNG                                                                                SSKTXOYMOBETGVWN                                                                                            DWYIMILEXQMSNUBJ
Read RAGTJQLWXLVBUOVQHPDZRPUZGLAIXTBUZKUXCWGCRIXZSEDXQPAVDWEKBT                    WNWFVVYDPEMCSFVQ                                RXCZSNOBEPPDKNBB                                            LCPFDVUXWETHVWJQ                                                        CPCCDTSOCLSEXIST                                                                    QZFCQWMQVEXTOGNG                                                                                SSKTXOYMOBETGVWN                                                                                            DWYIMILEXQMSNUBJ
Read AGTJQLWXLVBUOVQHPDZRPUZGLAIXTBUZKUXCWGCRIXZSEDXQPAVDWEKBT                    WNWFVVYDPEMCSFVQ                                RXCZSNOBEPPDKNBB                                            LCPFDVUXWETHVWJQ                                                        CPCCDTSOCLSEXIST                                                                    QZFCQWMQVEXTOGNG                                                                                SSKTXOYMOBETGVWN                                                                                            DWYIMILEXQMSNUBJ
Read GTJQLWXLVBUOVQHPDZRPUZGLAIXTBUZKUXCWGCRIXZSEDXQPAVDWEKBT                    WNWFVVYDPEMCSFVQ                                RXCZSNOBEPPDKNBB                                            LCPFDVUXWETHVWJQ                                                        CPCCDTSOCLSEXIST                                                                    QZFCQWMQVEXTOGNG                                                                                SSKTXOYMOBETGVWN                                                                                            DWYIMILEXQMSNUBJ
```

I expected to retrieve the below but's that's not the case:

Read AGTJXZMCFXENBQOH
Read QLWXLIBKRPELYHPR
Read VBUOVQICIOOTOTYK
Read HPDZRPUGIYAFBGJE
Read ZGLAIXTBGVCLJAGC
Read UZKUXCWGCIVJLMAF

Please what's wrong with my retrieve() function. Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this even compile? The `while-loop` inside the retrieving method you have written `start<long` which is incorrect? That should be `start<end` I think that's what you meant.

Comment: You are reading a line, then advancing one byte and reading the same line (minus the first byte) all over again.

Comment: Sorry the long in the while loop was a type. Made the correction. Thank you.

Comment: Your `retrieve()` method makes no sense. Even if it compiled, which it doesn't, whatever it reads gets thrown away. Its signature should be `String retrieve(long idx)`, and its implementation is trivial. No loop. And you can't treat an autoincrementing `long` as also an offset into the file. Make up your mind. It isn't a record number, it is a byte offset.

Comment: And your code doesn't print anything, so it is unclear what you're talking about in the first place.

Comment: The results I posted where from a test. I just created dummy messages(printing them as I store). Also, this is my first time using RandomAccessFile so I'm not sure how it works(like retrieving stuff should use offsets and as such). That's why I'm asking for feedback. Thank you

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense without the actual code. According to your comment you are printing as you store, but your question talks about objects being retrieved out of order, which doesn't make sense unless you are printing what you retrieve as well, and you have neither shown nor described that process. You need to write a complete, answerable question, and you clearly need to have a good think about what other people need to answer it.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough. I have made some edits. Please let me know if it's more clear what I'm trying to do. Also thank you for the feedback

Comment: What are you expecting your `seek` calls to do? Go to a given line number? They don't. They go to a given byte offset.

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

1. What is your newLine exactly, it should be "\n".
2. When you read that file in your while loop, you do not need to call

   file.seek(start);

   at all. Cause the cursor will automatically goes to the next line after

   file.readLine();

Comment: newLine should be System.lineSeparator(). And it's not just the reading that's the problem, but the writing too.